# A Warped Chess Maze

Tags: chess, mazes

[image]

A chess maze is a kind of chess puzzle where:

> 1. Only one side moves (and that side usually only has one piece).
> 2. That side must capture a piece with every move.
> 3. The goal is to capture all of the opposing pieces.

This chess maze is special, though. White always moves. Whenever White's only piece makes a capture, it turns into the piece it just captured. For example, on 1. Rxg1 a possible next move is 2. Nxh3.

Clarification: If the white piece turns into a pawn, it moves the same way as a *white* pawn.

A correct solution will have no pieces remaining except a white king on h8.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this may be the solution:

> 1. Rxa5 
>  2. Bxd8 
>  3. Bxf6 
>  4. Nxd5 
>  5. Rxd2 
>  6. Bxh6 
>  7. Nxf7 
>  8. Rxa7 
>  9. Bxg1 
> 10. Nxh3 
>  11. Rxh5 
>  12. Bxg6 
>  13. gxh7 
>  14. Rxh8

Comment: Nice answer! Think I might’ve got you though! ;) +1 from me!!

Comment: Giving my +1 here because of the typo in the slightly faster answer, which wasn't fixed until after this was posted.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7U0q.png) is a visual guide

Answer (score 10):

Let’s see:

> 1. Rxa5 
>  2. Bxd8 
>  3. Bxf6 
>  4. Nxd5 
>  5. Rxd2 
>  6. Bxh6 
>  7. Nxf7 
>  8. Rxa7 
>  9. Bxg1 
>  10. Nxh3 
>  11. Rxh5 
>  12. Bxg6 
>  13. gxh7 
>  14. Rxh8

Comment: Darn I took too long double checking. I think you might have made a typo in your 3. the bishop cant move along d

Comment: Whoops! That was supposed to be f. Good catch, thanks @gabbo1092!