# A Fairy Warped Chess Maze

Tags: chess, mazes

So, my previous puzzle [A Warped Chess Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73947/a-warped-chess-maze) is somehow my highest voted puzzle on Puzzling SE. So, I'm bringing it back, now with fairy pieces!

The fairy pieces will be explained in a bit, but the basic rules for a chess maze are:

> 1. Only one side moves (and that side usually only has one piece).
> 2. That side must capture a piece with every move.
> 3. The goal is to capture all of the opposing pieces.
> 4. (for warped chess mazes only) Whenever you capture a piece, your piece becomes the type of piece you captured.

Now, I'll explain the fairy pieces used below.

> **Pawns** have their movement options reversed. They move one space forward diagonally but capture one space straight forward.
>
> **Knights** are now slightly modified versions of **knightriders**. They can make any number of knight moves in the same direction.
>
> **Bishops** and **rooks** can now only move an even number of spaces in their movement direction. However, they CAN jump over pieces an odd number of spaces away.
>
> **Queens** are now **amazons**, which can move as a queen OR knight.

Here's a few diagrams illustrating how every new piece captures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Got it? Here's the maze.

[image]

Again, a correct solution will have only a white king on h8. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Solution:

> 1. Rxa5 
>  2. Bxc7  
>  3. Nxf1  
>  4. Rxf7  
>  5. Qxe5  
>  6. Bxc3  
>   7. Nxg5  
>   8. Bxe7  
>  9. Nxg6  
>  10. gxg7  
>  11. gxg8  
>  12. Rxa8  
>  13. Qxh1  
>  14. Qxh8

Method:

> Started by finding what moves were possible from the start. Then looked to find areas where a piece could only capture one piece to narrow down chunks of moves. Tested through possible routes.

Comment: Yeah, that's it.